# Aiogram: strange error in calback handler

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a callback button by aiogram and when i try to send a message  with keyboard:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="question", reply_markup=keyboard_markup)
```

it trows an error:

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse inline keyboard button: inlinekeyboardbutton must be an object
```

So i check types of buttons and markup:

```
<class 'aiogram.types.inline_keyboard.InlineKeyboardMarkup'>
<class 'aiogram.types.inline_keyboard.InlineKeyboardButton'>
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add `keyboard_markup` creation. Seems trouble is in it :)

Example:

```py
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

async def foo():
    # create your reply_markup object
    keyboard= InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    # create button
    button = InlineKeyboardButton("Button", callback_data="button_data")

    # add button to markup
    keyboard.add(button)

    # send message
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="question", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in your keyboard "keyboard_markup"
your keyboard should look like this

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

keyboard_markup= InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard=[
        [
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="...some text",
                             callback_data="...some text")
        ]
    ]
)
```

i suggest you forgot put second square bracket in variable 'inline_keyboard'